# How to get the rating without login in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rating

I would like to send a customer, a link to rate via sms or email. 
For example, I am planning to use [given code](https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate). 
This should work only once and the page should open without login. 
Please throw some light on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a token to use in the link... with a migration add a field 'token' to the order item (or whatever you call the order line)

```
rails g migration add_token_to_order_item token:token
```

The migration will both generate the field and will create an index for rapid retrieval of the record via token.  Also add `has_secure_token` to the table.

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_token
  ...
end
```

Create a route for the link that you'll include in the SMS or email, do this in routes.rb

```
get 'enter_review/:token', to: 'reviews#enter_review'
```

Then in your email or SMS you'll have...

```
<%= link_to nil, enter_review_reviews_url(@order_item.token) %>
```

The `nil` will cause the link itself to be displayed, so you can add some text like "if you can't click on the link, copy and paste it into your browser" if they have a restrictive email client.

Make sure the action does not require a log in, by modifying your ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: -> { customer_rating? }

  private

  def customer_rating?
    params[:controller] == 'reviews' && params[:action] == 'enter_review'
  end

end
```

And in your controller `ReviewsController` you would have something like...

```
class ReviewsController

  def enter_review
    @order_item = OrderItem.find_by(token: params[:token])
    unless @order_item
      # redirect to a "sorry, cannot find this order..." page and then return
    end
    ...
  end

end
```

Note that after they enter a review, they'll probably click some `Submit` button to a post action... you'll need a route for that action, you'll need the action defined in your controller, and you'll need to extend `customer_rating?` to ensure the post action doesn't require the user to be logged in.

At the end of your post action, do...

```
@order_item.regenerate_token
```

...which will regenerate the token so that the rating link is one time only.

Answer (score 0):

Add two fields to customer model:

1. confirmation_id - uniq confirmation id,
2. confirmed - boolean, default false

After that send to user link with public url like www.yoursite.com/confirmation?confirmation_id=cb3cdd6

in confirmations_controller you can add something like this for example:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(confirmation_id: params[:confirmation_id])
  user.update(confirmed: true) if user.present? && !user.confirmed

  (some redirects and other actions)
end
```